# how to update all anchor href from string using php

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I have to update all href tags with in the string using php.
ex:

```
<a href="test.com">test</a> lorum <a href="ola.com">ipsum</a>
so i want to change href as <a href="http://ourdomain.com?url=test.com">test</a>
lorum <a href="http://ourdomain.com?url=ola.com">ipsum</a>
```

please tell me how to update all anchore href

Here i am doing like this but not updating correctly

```
$replaceStr  = "http://affilate.domain.com?cam=1&url=";
$html="<a href="test.com">test</a> lorum <a href="ola.com">ipsum</a>";
$match = array();
$url   = preg_match_all('/<a [^>]*href="(.+)"/', $html, $match);
if(count($match))
{
for($j=0; $j<count($match); $j++)
{
$html = str_replace($match[1][$j], $replaceStr.urlencode($match[1][$j]), $html);
}
}
```

Comment: I would discourage you to use regexes for this, it is a much safer bet to use an existing HTML parser (PHP has options for this). This website explains why regexes are a bad idea for this and offers a better PHP solution: [htmlparsing.com](http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=href=")([^"]*)
```

Try this.Replace by `http://ourdomain.com?url=$1`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/11

```
$re = "/(?<=href=\")([^\"]*)/im";
$str = "<a href=\"test.com\">test</a> lorum <a href=\"ola.com\">ipsum</a>";
$subst = "http://ourdomain.com?url=$1";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```